# Photo grid in Bootstrap without margins

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve photo grid in Bootstrap without margins like this and also this has to be full-width, I solved that by puting all in container-fluid and no-gutter..
[image: pic],

but I don't know where I'm wrong. Biggest problem is actually the bigger photo, I need to align it, without any borders or margins, I tried to create, like you can see in 
[DEMO](https://jsbin.com/yivitisime/edit?output), another col-lg-6 to get this size, and other photos are col-lg-3. Don't know what's the problem

Comment: You need to post your code (simplified, into an [mcve]) to your question.  External links can become unavailable for a number of reasons, making the question incomplete and impossible to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope it will help you

```
.img-responsive {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
}
.portfolio-box {
position: relative;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/zositiyece/1/edit?output)

Comment: Thank you, that's it pretty much. Now just to do some minor changes

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to modify core Bootstrap classes like that. Instead, create your own class.

Answer (score 1):

This could help. First I classed the left side portfolio-box with a class I can use for specificity. Then I added this to the CSS

```
 .portfolio-box.left-side{
   height: 480px;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 .left-side > img{
    width:100% !important;
 }
```

This is the additional class to the HTML

```
<a href="#" class="portfolio-box left-side">
```

Here is a link to the [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMJoEy?editors=110)

Comment: It helped, just changed the height to 520px, to justify it with the right side.. But now I need to have full-width, and that there is no any kind of gap between left picture and the others

Answer (score 1):

I'd apply a negative margin equal to your gutter width to the children of your grid columns, and a matching padding:

```
.gallery-image {
  margin: -15px;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="gallery-image">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5a9drqx1/4)**